# Is the function nnet adapted for neural network with a text?

Tags: prediction, using, nnet

I am trying to make a neural network model to predict sentiment about a text.

I have a data frame BDD with 3 columns:

1) there are adjectives. The name of the column is "ADJ"

2) there are nouns. The name of the column is "NOUN"

3) It's 1 if adj+noun is positive, -1 if negative and 0 if neutral. The name of the column is "V3"

BDD is divided with BDD_train and BDD_test.  I succeeded to make my model, but the problem is when I make prediction.

This is the result of the model with BDD_train:

```
# weights:  476
initial  value 133.618585 
iter  10 value 18.334323
iter  20 value 15.922404
iter  30 value 15.823113
iter  40 value 15.816471
iter  50 value 15.811491
iter  60 value 15.811371
iter  60 value 15.811371
iter  60 value 15.811371
final  value 15.811371 
converged
```

```
nn_model <- nnet(V3~.,data = BDD_train,size = 5,decay = 1,linout = TRUE, maxit = 500)

pred2 <- predict(nn_model,newdata = BDD_test)
```

My error message is :

```
"Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit, xlev = object$xlevels) :
 le facteur ADJ a des nouveaux niveaux accommodative, Annual, Apparent, aware, definitive, federal, Good, greater, healthy, Monthly, more"
```

Comment: Is the textual content of the dataset encoded? Could you add some example of the content of those columns? It seems that the model is not able to take into account the new words that apparently were not considered in the training stage.